# default drawables in android studio 1.0.2 like abc_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light

Tags: android, android-drawable

I tried using @drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame or abc_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light but didnt work, can you help me by listing good shadows provided default like aboves

Comment: @aashima, why remove tag android-studio?? i have read somewhere @drawable/abc_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light was available in a android 0.8.6 but not higher ver, negative marking without knowing :(

Comment: I thought that right cos your question has more focus on default drawables. But you can keep your tags as they were if u want.. your choice :) P.S didn't vote down your answer..

Answer (score 1):

I did iterative checking @drawable/abc_ and found @drawable/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult to be of my need, may be it would be help to someone :D